# sort command giving unexpected output

Tags: linux, sorting, terminal, csh

I have two files with same string in column but in different order.

**file test1:**

```
testbench.clk1 667 
testbench.clk1_temp_net 667 
testbench.clk 2000
```

and **file test2:**

```
testbench.clk1 533 
testbench.clk 1611     
testbench.clk1_temp_net 538
```

I run sort command on column 1 as follows on both files and it give different output :

```
sort -t " " -k1 test1

testbench.clk1 667
testbench.clk1_temp_net 667
testbench.clk 2000

sort -t " " -k1 test2

testbench.clk1 533
testbench.clk 1611
testbench.clk1_temp_net 538
```

can you explain why i am getting this output and what is the correct solution for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `info sort`:

> Many options affect how ‘sort’ compares lines; if the results are
>   unexpected, try the ‘--debug’ option to see what happened.

Let's do that (on my de_DE.utf8 system)

```
sort --debug -k1 file1
sort: es werden die Sortierregeln für »de_DE.utf8“ verwendet
sort: führende Leerzeichen sind signifikant in Schlüssel 1: Sie sollten daher wahrscheinlich auch „b“ angeben
```

Unfortunately it makes no sense to run the command in English to show what happens. To translate it:

```
sort: sorting rules for »de_DE.utf8“ in use
sort: preceding whitspace is significant in key 1: You might want to use „b“
```

When I run the command with:

```
LANG=C sort -k1b file1
```

which can be just

```
LANG=C sort -b file1
```

the order looks ok. I guess it is a locale problem for you too.

---

Btw, if you want a hierarchical sort field1, field2 then use:

```
LANG=C sort -k1,1b -k2,2n file
```

---

The question was tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) but it turned out that the OP is using `csh`. In that case you need to pass `$LANG` like this:

```
env LANG=C sort ...
```

Comment: oh sorry i tried all options and like -k1 or -k1,1. so accidentally put it in description. Already updated the description. Thanks a lot

Comment: You had also -n in one of your commands. are you sure that it will now give this result?

Comment: @MarekVitek i checked it after removing -n option (numeric sort). And it is giving wrong output

Comment: I've updated my answer. Can you check if that works for you?

Comment: sort LANG=C -k1b test1
sort: open failed: LANG=C: No such file or directory

i am getting above error.

Comment: `LANG=C sort -k1b file1`

Comment: i have system :
$ uname -a
Linux inndr4 2.6.18-308.el5 #1 SMP Fri Jan 27 17:17:51 EST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: that's hard to believe. `LANG=C` is a shell variable, which set's the locale for the `sort` command. Which shell are you using?

Comment: csh shell used.
echo $SHELL
/bin/csh

Comment: In `csh` it would be `env LANG=C sort ...`

Comment: Glad to see that it works. I admit that I was also confused.

Comment: Using `LANG=C` forces sort to do byte comparison. So for some languages it will result in wrong sort order.

Answer (score 0):

To sort correctly you need to specify keys by which you will sort your data by the first and then by the second column in your list.

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2 test1

testbench.clk 2000
testbench.clk1 667
testbench.clk1_temp_net 667
```

and for file2

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2 test2

testbench.clk 1611
testbench.clk1 533
testbench.clk1_temp_net 538
```

If you use just -k1 as you did, then it will take first key up to the end of line - which is same as default sort. The problem is that apparently sort treats spaces between numbers as thousand separator as it is in some languages. Which makes `testbench.clk 1611` into `testbench.clk1611` and `testbench.clk1 533` into `testbench.clk1533` even if numeric sort is not used.

There is no need to mess with LANG or LC_COLLATE variables. Doing so you might cause your sort to produce wrong results for certain languages. E.g. character `č` used in Czech language, and many other, will then be sorted incorrectly.

Comment: Why `-V` (*version sort*)?

Comment: @hek2mgl I am not really sure. I would expect this behavior without any option. I don't know why it is called version-sort, But man page says `natural sort of (version) numbers within text` whatever the version there means. Try this one `printf "aa bb\naab b\na abb\na cbb" | sort -V` then try it without -V and compare results.

Comment: Correct would be to use `-b` - as I showed in my answer ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl Well I wasn't thinking straight. But here is my corrected answer. I hope You will agree with that. It seems that you have got it almost right :-).